# How to find out in CMakeLists.txt if a variable in cmake cache is outdated

Tags: c, cmake

I have a bunch of variables passed to cmake to be used as preprocessor macros in a C program, which this snippet of CMakeLists.txt enables (at first sight):

```
if(DEFINED {MYVAR})
    add_compile_definitions(MYVAR)
endif()
```

When I just NOT want to define a variable `MYVAR`, which I have previously used, cmake passes the variable anyways, taking it from the cache. For these cases, I want to unset the variable if it was not passed to cmake as a `-D` option:

```
unset(MYVAR CACHE)
```

Now the [Cmake documentation on if(DEFINED ..)](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/if.html) clearly states that it is not possible to find out if a variable is defined ONLY in cache and was not passed as a `-D` on the command line in the current run. But then how DO I find out? Simply unsetting in cache before the if does not work.

Comment: I think the right answer would be to reconfigure a project with new options.  If you want to use the same build folder, you can use `cmake -UMYVAR <build-folder>`.

Comment: In my case the options only concern a very small part of the project - trying to avoid rebuilding the whole embedded OS every time, this is why I'm looking for a "local" option. The -U forces me to explicitly unset a macro in every variant where I don't use it, which seems error-prone. Is there really no way to check it in the CMakeLists file?

Comment: The expected use case (as far as I'm aware anyway) is that most configuration changes are to add targets, source files, etc.  Change options (what you're doing) is the exception, so I'm not aware of any built in way.  If the part you're changing is truly isolated, maybe you can pull that into a separate project and grab it via `find_package`, that way you don't need to rebuild everything.